# Erro ao iniciar servidor Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Estou inserindo duas dependências hibernate no meu pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Quando inicio o servidor Tomcat dá erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Log no console:

> INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained
>   no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of
>   JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping
>   unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP
>   compilation time. fev 16, 2018 11:34:20 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal GRAVE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5fd5d6d1]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>   .....................
>
> fev 16, 2018 11:34:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] fev 16, 2018
>   11:34:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] fev 16, 2018 11:34:20 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Stopping service [Catalina] fev 16, 2018 11:34:20 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] fev 16, 2018 11:34:20 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

Answer (score 0):

**Tomcat 8.5 .** Dentro de catalina.properties, localizado no conjunto de diretórios / conf:

`tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=\*.jar`

Ou vá para context.xml, localizado no diretório / conf da Tomcat e adicione:

`<JarScanner scanClassPath="false"/>`

Comment: tentei os dois modos, porém o erro persiste.